# Writing Kernel extensions for AIX

Tags: aix

I am about to embark on a journey to write some kernel extensions for AIX 6.1.

I would be very very great full to the community ,if they could provide me some assistance in finding books , articles , blogs..whatever info i can get.

I have already checked the IBM site. But I need more info.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: WOW!!! 3 views...gr8..
atleast someone viewed the question...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of IBM Redbooks available:

Don't worry too much if they are for older versions of AIX, there has not be that much change since 5.1 and may things from even older versions still apply.

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245674.html (developing and porting C/C++ programs)
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg244946.html (writing reliable AIX daemons)
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246034.html (AIX 5L porting guide)

I hope you have seen the official documentation: (Kernel Extensions and Device Support Programming Concepts)
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.kernelext/doc/kernextc/kernextc.htm

Markus